# what collection do you use to accept the return value of select 1 from oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have an oracle table, and I want to check for existence.

`Select 1 from table where match_id = 'xxxx'` would return 0 row, 1 row, or many rows of 1s depending on how many matches there are.

I'm using myBatis to write the sql, so what kind of collection should i use to accept the result?

Comment: Why not use a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` that would give you the number of matching records directly?

Comment: because count is slower than select 1, and I'm after the efficiency and speed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `EXISTS` by selecting from dual

```
SELECT
     CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
               SELECT 1
               FROM tablename
               WHERE match_id = 'xxxx'
          ) THEN 1                  --exists
          ELSE 0                    --does not exists
     END
FROM dual;
```

Or restrict the result using `ROWNUM = 1` and then do count

```
select count(*) from 
(
  Select 1 from tablename where match_id = 'xxxx' and rownum = 1
);
```

Both should have similar performance and better than doing `select count(*)` on entire table.

Comment: thanks, but does this make it slower than simply select 1 and take the result to the code? I'm dealing with 70million+ records, so even a slight performance decrease will have an impact big time.

Comment: @Andy : There shouldn't be a performance impact with the methods I've shown.You can compare it to your main sql  by doing an  `EXPLAIN PLAN` for both or noting the time taken for execution of both.

Comment: ahh I like your edit. That's smart. Thanks, I'll try it out.